Difference between reghdfe and fixest for a multiple FE regression?
I am estimating the following equation using fixest:
$$
Y_{i,f,s,t} = \beta_1 treat_i + \beta_2 post_t +  \beta_3 treat_i*post_t + \alpha_i + \alpha_{s,t} + \alpha_{f,t}  + \epsilon_{i,f,s,t}
$$
where i is the individual, f is the year that the individual was born, s is the area, t is year. I am looking at the effect of a policy that affected certain individuals (treat_i is fixed at the individual level). I want to control for differential trends by year an individual is born (non-linearly, this is important for my specification as age effects are different across the years), and differential trends by subject area, that is why i have them as two fixed effects, along with the individual FE.
Here is how i estimate this in R using fixest:
feols(y ~ treat*post | individual + subject_area^year + first_year^year, data=df)
The issue is, when I include both age by year and subject by year FE, the model gives me an estimate for beta1, when that should be absorbed by individual FE. The standard errors are huge (making P-value = 0.99, and this coefficient not discernible from 0), but I am puzzled to why the model estimates it in the first place.
Indeed, when I run the same regression in Stata, the coefficient is not estimated as it is found collinear with FE. The coefficient of interest, beta3, is the same across the two packages. Here is how I estimate it with reghdfe:
reghdfe y treat##post, absorb(individual subject_area##year first_year##year) cluster(individual)
Do you know what goes behind the scenes? I think the problem might be stemming from small group sizes, but I wonder why fixest estimates a coefficient (while reghdfe doesn't)?
UPDATE: I realised this might to do with collinearity threshold in fixest which probably is different than reghdfe. Indeed when I set collin.tol = 1e-09 (instead of default 1e-10) beta1 was no longer estimated by fixest due to collinearity. Still would love to understand why.
